# Is it possible to use scss function in reverse?

Tags: sass

This is one of CSS Gradient maker example.
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

```
background-color: #ffb76b; // Old browsers
@include filter-gradient(#ffb76b, #ff7f04, vertical); // IE6-9
@include background-image(linear-gradient(top, #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%));
```

In this example `#ffb76b` is base color.

I think there is a function or combination of functions that maps two colors.
For exmaple, like `function_foo(#ffb76b) -> #ffa73d`, or `function_bar(#ffb76b) -> #ff7c00`

This `function_foo` and `function_bar` can be expressed by scss functions. (I think)

```
adjust-hue($color, $degrees)
lighten($color, $amount)
darken($color, $amount)
saturate($color, $amount)
desaturate($color, $amount)
```

Is there way to determine the function, if a input value and a output value are given?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a start colour and an end colour. I want to know the sass transform required to achieve the end colour so that I can apply the same transform to other colours in my palette.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve from a programming standpoint. If you need a color that's lighter than the one you have, you should use the lighten() function. If you need something darker, use darken().

You also may want to consider thinking about the color values either as RGB or as HSL. This is going to give you a much more meaningful color value and you'd then be able to use something like the [adjust_color() function](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adjust_color-instance_method).

Ultimately, if you need a color, I would say you should explicitly define it using variables. Nothing in Sass itself is going to tell you which function to use to get which result.

If you need a visual comparison tool, you maybe could try using [A visual guide to Sass & Compass color functions: http://jackiebalzer.com/color](http://jackiebalzer.com/color);

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The sentence you wrote, "Nothing in SASS itself is going to tell you which function to use to get which result" is what I want to know. But maybe there is a way outside scss to accomplish it. So make this question stay open.

Answer (score -1):

Sass has a `darken` function which does the opposite of `lighten`. http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wish I could ask more understandable. I don't want to know the function itself but if two value is given how can I know what function are needed. Is there something like `meta function`?